# Find: $\lim_{x \to\infty}\left(\frac{2}{x} +1\right)^{\frac{x}{2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find 
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(\frac{2}{x} +1\right)^{\frac{x}{2}}$$

I don't know how to approach this. I tried to replace $x$ by $\infty$, but then I would have $1^{\infty}$

Comment: This limit is one of the definitions of the number $e$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant x, not n.

Comment: Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#History) out.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=2n$, when $x\to +\infty$, $n \to +\infty$.
$$\lim_{x→ +\infty} \left( \frac{2}{x} +1\right)^{\frac{x}{2}}=\lim_{x→ +\infty} \left( \frac{2}{2n} +1\right)^{\frac{2n}{2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be :

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(\frac{2}{x} +1\right)^{\frac{x}{2}}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(\left(\frac{2}{x}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{\color{red}{\frac{2}{x}}}}\right)^{\color{red}{\frac{2}{x}}\cdot\frac{x}{2}}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\exp\left(\frac{2}{x}\cdot\frac{x}{2}\right)=\exp(1)=e$$